# Issue with multi threading , as producer consumer are executed only once despite wait and notify usage

Tags: java, multithreading

I have written the following program for inter thread communication ,, which is simply supposed to produce and consume one by one and program should keep running and printing until stopped externally .

```
package multithreading;

public class WaitNotifyExample
{
    private final int asd;

    public WaitNotifyExample(int asd)
    {
        this.asd = asd;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        CounterWaitNotifyExample counter = new CounterWaitNotifyExample(0);
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ConsumerWaitNotifyExample(counter));
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new ProducerWaitNotifyExample(counter));


        t2.start();
        t1.start();
    }
}

class ConsumerWaitNotifyExample implements Runnable
{

    CounterWaitNotifyExample counter;

    public ConsumerWaitNotifyExample(CounterWaitNotifyExample counter)
    {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
                counter.consume();
        }
    }
}

class ProducerWaitNotifyExample implements Runnable
{

    CounterWaitNotifyExample counter;

    public ProducerWaitNotifyExample(CounterWaitNotifyExample counter)
    {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
            counter.produce();
    }
}

class CounterWaitNotifyExample
{
    private int counter;
    private boolean produced =false;

    public CounterWaitNotifyExample(int counter)
    {
        this.setCounter(counter);
    }

    public synchronized void consume()
    {
        if(!produced)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("consumed "+--counter);
        produced = false;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public synchronized void produce()
    {
        if(produced)
        {
            try
            {
                wait();
            } catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("produced "+(++counter));
        produced = true;
        notifyAll();
    }

    public int getCounter()
    {
        return counter;
    }

    public void setCounter(int counter)
    {
        this.counter = counter;
    }
}
```

but i only get the following output , as application is still running but  nothing is printing , meaning , producer and consumer are not executed any further.

```
produced 1
consumed 0
```

what Am I doing wrong here conceptually ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your producer doesn't have any loop. Only your consumer has.

Also, read the javadoc of `wait()`. It must always be called inside a **loop** checking for a condition.

Comment: i am extremely ashamed for such a stupid mistake ,thanks a ton